# Sorting by columns in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to sort by descending value in column h in vba.

The code i'm using is the following;

```
 With .Range("a8:h" & Rowindex - 1)
 .Sort Key1:=Range(.Cells(9, 8), .Cells(Rowindex, 8)), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
End With
```

Rowindex is my row count.

However when i run this, i get the following error;

"Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"

Comment: Did you mean `ws.Range(ws.Cells(9, 8), ws.Cells(Rowindex, 8))`? Where `ws` is the worksheet object?

Comment: Are you inside another `With` block? Why is there a `.` *dot* before the `Range()` near the `With`?

Comment: Yes it is in another with block. The with block is "With worksheet"

Comment: Is rowindex - 1 greater than 0 when the error is thrown?

Comment: @Chrislaar123: I guess you missed my comment? Your `.Cells(9, 8)` are referring to `.Range("a8:h" & Rowindex - 1)`

Comment: Sorry Siddharth, I don't follow you. Could you explain further. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Sort Key1:=.Range("a8:h" & Rowindex - 1), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
```